# Untar file in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tar

I want to untar a file in Ubuntu but as I enter this command

```
tar xvf filename.tgz
```

I receive the following errors:

```
tar: filename.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` to go into the directory on which the file.tgz file is located and then run the below command to extract its content.

```
tar -zxvf file.tgz
```